# Reading non-english characters from Postgres database in Informatica

Tags: postgresql, unicode, utf-8, informatica-powercenter

I have an informatica mapping that reads data from a postgres database. The Informatica Integration service is running in UNICODE mode. I have set the code page of the ODBC connection that connects to postgres as UTF-8.

While debugging the mapping or executing the session, Informatica fails to read characters that are not in English, eg : Russian or Chinese. In the debug instance window the characters from the database are converted to junk characters.

Please let me know if there is a work around for this issue, so that I can properly ready data from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the issue. It appears I need to configure the Informatica odbc.ini file. Since I was using ODBC connection to read data from postgres, I have to explicitly define the code page of the odbc driver in the ini file. 
If it is not defined, the default value is ISO 8859-1 Latin-1.

To set this value add the parameter IANAAppCodePage=106 , where 106 is UTF-8, for your odbc connection in the odbc.ini file.

More details can be found here - https://kb.informatica.com/solution/5/Pages/18253.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order to read non English or Unicode character you need to set code pafe to UTF-8 under both DB level and Infa Intergration Service level.

Also check the code page in Repository DB